# Questions about probability on defined choices.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

> A system administrator is going to install three laptops for three new
> recruited  employees of his company. He selects 3 laptops from a table
> that consists of 15  laptops at which these laptops are nicely
> arranged in a row on the table.
>
> - i. How many choices does he have?
> - ii. What is the probability for this to happen if he must select the
>   first or the fifth or  the last laptop but not any two or all of these
>   laptops?

For i)
I knew it is nCr which is 15C3 = 455
for ii) I;m clueless except i know the first,fifth and last laptop cannot both be chosen both at the same time and cannot three of them be chosen

Which is cannot choose such combinations:

1st 5th 15th | 5th 1st 15th | 5th 15th 1st| 15th 5th 1st| 15th 1st 5th | 1st 5th xth | 5th 1st xth | 1st 15th xth | 15th 1st xth | 15th 5th xth | 5th 15th xth

I assume that it is 1 minus above combinations? But i don't know how to express it.

Or anything about my concepts are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

The number of ways to pick $3$ objects from a set of size $15$ is indeed $C(15,3) = 15!/12!/3! = 455$.

If you must pick exactly $1$ from a subset of size $3$ then you must pick the other $2$ from the rest of the set which is of size $12$. The number of ways is hence:

$C(3,1)\times C(12,2) = (3!/2!/1!)\times (12!/10!/2!) = 3\times 66 = 198.$

The probability that the second event happens randomly is therefore $198/455$, about $0.435$.

Comment: Alright, so you means that i must first understood that the 3 laptops defined can only choose one of them, so it means 3C1, then the rest of the laptops left 12 of them, from there I can choose on any 2 laptops from 12 combinations. Then use the probability formula to find it's probability?

Comment: I think I had understood what you mean , thanks for the guidance mate !